# Coda-style tooltip, popup positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently hacking away, trying to replicate Coda's tooltip:
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/

Check out my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/Ccmh3/

I'm following this tutorial, and in this piece the position of the tooltip is hardcoded. However I want the position to adjust dynamically based on the dimensions of the tooltip, so that it is positioned precisely over the trigger-image.

I'm struggling a bit with this, first I wanted to obtain he position of the tooltip like this:

```
var width = $('.popup').width();
var height = $('.popup').height();
```

Next I tried to manipulate the position of the popup based on the dimensions of the popup. But my math skills is falling short, I don't have a clue on how to do this. This is my meager attempt:

```
    // reset position of popup box
    popup.css({
      top: -(.5*height),
      left: -(.5*width),
      display: 'block' // brings the popup back in to view
    })
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to go about this?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/Ccmh3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with this:

```
// reset position of popup box
    popup.css({
      top: -height,
      left: -(0.5*width)+5,
      display: 'block' // brings the popup back in to view
    })
```

The top attribute moves your tootltip above the hoovered element, the left attribute center it over the element. You must compensate also by half the size of your borders/padding/and so on (that's what the +5 does).

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ccmh3/23/ (after some comments, I also limited the size of the content width, this way, it works better)

Is it what you want?

Comment: thx for helping me out :)
It's not quite what I want, though. When I put more content in the popup it looks like this: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/228089/tooltip-1.png - I want it to look like this: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/228089/tooltip2.png

Comment: @timkl Ok, true, the code I gave you works, but when the tooltip has a width larger than the #container width, it doesn't work any more...

What you can do is either limit the width of the content of your toolbox: http://jsfiddle.net/Ccmh3/23/ (this works fine for me with any content).

Or you can try another approach without tables: http://www.uidesign.at/journal/2011/01/14/simple-tooltip-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: Roger that. I'm going to add a max-width to the .popup, that solves the problem http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/Ccmh3/ Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it needs a bit of tweaking but will work find with different height and width

```
 popup.css({
          top: -(0.8*height),
          left: -(0.5*width),
          display: 'block' // brings the popup back in to view
        });
```

try this on [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamranali/Ccmh3/20/)